# need help for a simple console program c#

Tags: c#

needing a simple console program for c# where i ask the user to input random arguments consists of mixed integer/string. and then i have to locate integers and use it as the number of times to print the strings in the input args so far i have these

```
Console.Write("please type in random letters, words, numbers: ");

string uInput = Console.ReadLine();

args.Count(uInput);
```

was told output should be somthing like this

some ran 3 dom st u f f s lke this 9  <<<< user input

dom st u f f s lke this 9               <<< pront output after user input

dom st u f f s lke this 9

dom st u f f s lke this 9

i'm hitting a wall here as i am not really sure how to use the "args" method. thank you for any response.

Comment: `args` isn't a method, and it wouldn't be appropriate to use here anyway.

Comment: If you want to prompt the user, then you don't need to worry about args. Maybe you want to get the uInput and split on each whitespace to get an array of words they have typed in.

Comment: I still don't understand what the output is supposed to be. Are you trying to count the number of words the user enters before pressing enter?

Comment: its like an assignment, my friend is teaching me but he just ask me to do stuffs like this and doesn't tell me exactly how or why. for this one though he wants me to use the "args" thing.

Comment: If you are using args, then don't worry about using Console.Write. Prompting the user is kind of useless in this case.

Comment: if i don't prompt for input where can i possibly get the args to be analyzed? i have edited an example output hope that helps.

Comment: bottom line, `args` do not come from a user prompt, they come from arguments supplied when you run the application; i.e `C:\myProgram\Myprogram.exe some ran 3 dom st u f f s lke this 9`.

Answer (score 1):

In Main, we access a string array called args. This **array** is populated with command-line arguments from the operating system. This makes it possible to configure programs with minimal complexity.

```
if (args == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("args is null"); // Check for null array
}
else
{
    Console.Write("args length is ");
    Console.WriteLine(args.Length); // Write array length
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) // Loop through array
    {
        string argument = args[i];
        Console.Write("args index ");
        Console.Write(i); // Write index
        Console.Write(" is [");
        Console.Write(argument); // Write string
        Console.WriteLine("]");
    }
}
```

This will show you how the command-line parameters are received from a Windows command line.

Comment: Since you must use the args, I think this code is what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you for this. i understand how this one works, but how is it possible to populate the args array? and by that i mean is to populate it by outside input which is why i have the console.readline stuffs going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Your console app will have arguments in the form of an array. You need to iterate thru each item and perform some validation to determine if the value is an integer value or a string. Once you have determined the type you can store is in another array and that can used to store only integers. Then you can iterate thru that and do what you must.

Another way is to look into linq and iterate thru a filtered result set.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you need exactly, args is a array or strings. Usually it allows us to read output `CommandLine` parameters.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if(args!= null && args.Length >0)
    {
        // Read parameters as args[0]. args[1] etc...
    }
    else
    {
        // if there are no commandline parameters/arguments.
        var input = Console.ReadLine(); // Read's user input.

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) // Since you want to print user input 3 times,you can do this way. 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(input);
        }           
    }               
}
```

Take a look at some sample Fiddler [Demonstration](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FjXW9i)